# Degree of $\sqrt[5]{2+\sqrt[3]{5+\sqrt{2}}} \cdot e^{2\pi i /3}$ as algebraic number

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

In this post, ‘degree’ means ‘degree as an algebraic integer’. Let $\alpha = \sqrt[5]{2+\sqrt[3]{5+\sqrt{2}}}$ I see that $f(\alpha)=0$ for the polynomial $f(x) = \big((x^{5}-2)^{3}-5)\big)^{2}-2$, which is of degree $30$. I have two questions:

1. I want to show that the degree of $\alpha$ is $30$. How can one argue that $\alpha$ indeed has degree $30$? Since $\sqrt[5]{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}}}$ has degree $30$, so I feel like it should not be difficult to prove that $\alpha$ has degree $30$ but I am struggling here.
2. To show that $\beta =\sqrt[5]{2+\sqrt[3]{5+\sqrt{2}}} \cdot e^{2\pi i /3}$ has degree equal to $$\text{degree }(\alpha) \times \text{degree } (e^{2\pi i/3}) = 30 \times 2 = 60$$ seems way harder to me. I do not even have much intuition into it and computations seem awful.

I did enter both of these questions into WolframAlpha and my guesses are correct. But I have no clue why. I would love to know reasons behind it. I know some Galois theory.

Comment: What does it mean for you degree of \alpha?

Comment: Isn't $\operatorname{deg}(e^{2\pi i/3}) = 3$ ?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Degree of $a$ is meant to say the smallest degree amongst the degrees of polynomials $g$ such that $g(a) = 0$. May be I should write degree as an algebraic number/integer. Sorry about that.

Comment: @lisyarus degree of primitive third root of unity is $2$ as an algebraic integer since it mimimal polynomial is $x^{2}+x+1$. I apologize for lack of clarity.

Comment: @GafarMaulik Indeed, my bad :)

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt2}$ has degree 6, but $$\sqrt[3]{(\sqrt2+1)^3}=\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt2+7}$$ has degree 2. Nested roots with addition inside don't always work perfectly with degrees.

Comment: One way is to check that $f(x)$ is irreducible $\pmod{11}$, so it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Might be easier to first show that $\beta^5 = (2+\sqrt[3]{5+\sqrt{2}})e^{-2\pi i/3}$ has degree 12. Perhaps also the fact that $\beta$ and $\bar{\beta}$ have the same minimal polynomial is useful?

Comment: You shouldn't always expect there to be a nice way to deal with such an expression - as mentioned above, you have to manually check that the radicals won't de-nest. The most obvious approach of just finding the minimal polynomial and using some theory to make this calculation tractable is what WA presumably does, and many other computer algebra systems will let you do. Computers are extremely good at this sort of thing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on doing the calculations by hand, here is one possible approach using algebraic number theory.

1. $\sqrt{2}$ generates a quadratic extension $K_2$ of ${\mathbb Q}$.
2. $5 + \sqrt{2}$ is not a cube in $K_2$ since its norm is $23$. Alternatively,
   if it is the cube of an element of $K_2$, it must be the cube of an algebraic
   integer $a + b \sqrt{2}$, which it is not. Thus
   $K_6 = K_2(\sqrt[3]{5 + \sqrt{2}})$ has degree $6$.
3. $2 + \sqrt[3]{5 + \sqrt{2}}$ is not a fifth power in $K_6$ because its
   norm down to $K_2$  is not (it is $2^3 + 5 + \sqrt{2} = 13 + \sqrt{2}$).
   This implies that $K_{30} = {\mathbb Q}(\alpha)$ has degree $30$.
4. This is Jyrki Lahtonen's argument: Clearly
   $K_{30}(\beta^3) = K_{30}$ and $\beta \not \in K_{30}$, hence
   $K_{30}(\beta) \ne K_{30}$, and this implies that $K_{30}(\beta) = K_{30}(e^{2\pi i/3})$ is a quadratic extension of $K_{30}$.

Comment: Great stuff! I'm probably a bit dense, but I could not fully follow the last step. If we looked at $\gamma=\root3\of2$ instead, then $\Bbb{Q}(\gamma)$ would also have a real embedding, but still $[\Bbb{Q}(\gamma e^{2\pi/3}):\Bbb{Q}]=[\Bbb{Q}(\gamma):\Bbb{Q}]$. I do think that reusing your argument we see that $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^3)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. After all, the argument about fifth powers is the only step where cubing would change anything, and there it is irrelevant. In other words $\Bbb{Q}(\beta^3)=K_{30}$. But $K_{30}\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ while $\beta\notin\Bbb{R}$, so  the claim follows.

Comment: Oh wow! I see why I could not figure out easily. I did start on step 2 by myself until I came back to see Franz’s answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: I apologize for asking it quite a few days after I accepted the answer. I was wondering how I would modify that last step if one had used $7th$ root of unity to define $\beta = \sqrt[5]{2+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}}\cdot e^{2i\pi/7}$? In that case, all we obtain is that $K(\beta)$ is an extension of $K_{30}$ of order dividing $6$. How would one actually surmise that the degree of extension is $6$?

Comment: The easiest way woud be observing that primes above $7$ ramify completely.